# Flickr API: Retina images for the new iPad

Tags: ios, image, retina-display, flickr

The photo sizes available in the Flickr API seem out of date: Flickr [recently introduced new photo sizes](http://blog.flickr.net/en/2012/05/03/introducing-two-new-photo-sizes-and-a-new-setting-for-pro-members/) for the retina display, but it doesn't seem possible to get these from the API.  However, apps such as FlickStackr [seem to be using](http://news.softpedia.com/news/FlickStackr-for-Flickr-2-5-Supports-iPad-Retina-Resolutions-273841.shtml) these new image sizes.  I'm currently loading original images for the new iPad, which aren't always available and are slow to load and render.  How can I use these new sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a flickr.photos.getSizes on one of my recent images, and received this response, in part:

```
<size label="Large" width="1024" height="768" source="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7224/7174681563_4fc5b7d952_b.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/32054489@N00/7174681563/sizes/l/" media="photo" />
<size label="Large 1600" width="1600" height="1200" source="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7224/7174681563_cbbb7ca273_h.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/32054489@N00/7174681563/sizes/h/" media="photo" />
<size label="Large 2048" width="2048" height="1536" source="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7224/7174681563_15742b18a2_k.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/32054489@N00/7174681563/sizes/k/" media="photo" />
```

Looks like the new suffixes break down like this:

- large, 1600 on longer side: h
- large, 2048 on longer side: k

Comment: I'm glad to see those new sizes are returned by the API, the documentation's obviously out of date.  Thanks for your answer.